# Compute multiple statistical number on 2D-data with scipy.stats.binned_statistic_2d

Tags: python, scipy, statistics, histogram, binning

I have a question regarding the function [scipy.stats.binned_statistic_2d](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.binned_statistic_2d.html), which is the following:

I have 2-D data (x,y,f(x,y)), and I want to bin the x-y-plane and compute some statistics per each bin. For doing so, I use the very handy function s`binned_statistic_2d`. 
But let's assume I want to calculate several statistical value per bin - let's say the mean and the median. Therefore I found it natural to try something like this

```
stats.binned_statistic_2d(data["x"], data["y"], data["f"], statistic = lambda x: [ np.mean(x), np.median(x) ], bins = bin_number )
```

But this doesn't work, as the `binned_statistic_2d` expects a statistic function which returns only a scalar, and not a list of scalars.

Of course I could instead call the `binned_statistic_2d` two times, but as the bin_number is quite high for me and also data is a huge dataframe, this needs to much time.

So, do you have an idea, what I can do instead of a multiple execution of `binned_statistic_2d`, when I want to compute several statistical functions at once with this function?

For playing around, a small working example:

```
import pandas as pd
from scipy import stats

df = pd.DataFrame([  [i,j,i*j] for i in range(10) for j in range(10)], columns = ["x", "y", "f"])
# The following works
hist, _, _, _ = stats.binned_statistic_2d(df["x"], df["y"], df["f"], statistic = lambda x:  np.mean(x)  ,bins=4)    
# The following doesn't work
hist, _, _, _ = stats.binned_statistic_2d(df["x"], df["y"], df["f"], statistic = lambda x:  [ np.mean(x), np.median(x) ]  ,bins=4)
```

Thanks in advance,
Jürgen

Answer (score 0):

You want to use [`pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html#pandas-dataframe-pivot-table).  You can specify multiple functions to aggregate using `aggfunc`.